# Server Response 400: Field is required on Post request using android

Tags: android, python, django, apache, jinja2

The server side Django response if i click only the post method but when i sedn from mobile fields after entering the data the same response comes to android debug of 400 error as nothing has been entered

[image]

The Response by the server when using debugger states a 400 response and I'm using the `getErrorStream()` method to get the specific problem but still, I am entering the data but the response from the server is that I need that specific field to enter data. The title field is mandatory in the database but others fields are not. Check...

[image]

Code of the server:

private class SendDeviceDetails extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String data = "";

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        try {

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);



            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes("PostData=" + params[1]);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int code = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Response code of the object is "+code);

            InputStream in;
            if (code >= 200 && code < 400) {
                // Create an InputStream in order to extract the response object
                in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            }
            else {
                in = httpURLConnection.getErrorStream();

            }
            Log.d("FOR_LOG", String.valueOf(httpURLConnection));
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
            while (inputStreamData != -1) {
                char current = (char) inputStreamData;
                inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                data += current;
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return data;
    }private class SendDeviceDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String data = "";

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        try {

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes("PostData=" + params[1]);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int code = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Response code of the object is "+code);

            InputStream in;
            if (code >= 200 && code < 400) {
                // Create an InputStream in order to extract the response object
                in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            }
            else {
                in = httpURLConnection.getErrorStream();

            }
            Log.d("FOR_LOG", String.valueOf(httpURLConnection));
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
            while (inputStreamData != -1) {
                char current = (char) inputStreamData;
                inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                data += current;
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("TAG", result); // this is expecting a response code to be sent                  from your server upon receiving the POST data
    }
}
```

The Code of button Click which is in Oncreate Method

```
    title = findViewById(R.id.sendtitle);
    platform = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sendtechnology);
    date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.senddate);
    description = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sendescription);

  Button submitButton = findViewById(R.id.uploaddata);

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();


            try {

                //Button image = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendImage);

                postData.put("title", title.getText().toString());
                postData.put("technology", platform.getText().toString());
                postData.put("date", date.getText().toString());
                postData.put("description", description.getText().toString());
                //postData.put("image", image.getText().toString());
                //postData.put("deviceID", deviceID.getText().toString());

                if((title == null) ){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Enter Title",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {

                    new SendDeviceDetails().execute("http://url/data/details/", postData.toString());
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi. Can you share your SendDeviceDetails code?

Comment: what's your code on server side?

Comment: The code of the server is as follows ...

Comment: You don't actually seem to have shown the server code. Where is the Django code that is producing that response?